# local_action: shell error concatenate files

Tags: ansible

There is such an error in my playbook. Why and how to fix it? (getting the list of updates of remote-hosts, concatenate lists into one file)

```
- name: Save update_deb_packs in file on ansible-host
    copy:
      content: "{{ update_deb_packs.stdout }}"
      dest: ~/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}_update_deb_packs
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: merge files from different hosts in once
    local_action: shell cat ~/tmp/* > ~/tmp/list_update
```

result:

```
TASK [Save update_deb_packs in file on ansible-host] *******************************************
changed: [g33-linux -> 127.0.0.1]
changed: [dell-e6410 -> 127.0.0.1]

TASK [merge files from different hosts in once] ********************************
changed: [g33-linux -> localhost]
fatal: [dell-e6410 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cat ~/tmp/* > ~/tmp/list_update", "delta": "0:00:00.052968", "end": "2017-12-23 13:48:37.029706", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-12-23 13:48:36.976738", "stderr": "cat: /home/alex/tmp/list_update: input and output in one file", "stderr_lines": ["cat: /home/alex/tmp/list_update: input and output in one file"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/alex/.ansible/playbooks/update_deb_list.retry
```

directory `~/tmp` is empty. After **shell** result file (list_update) file exists and true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a glob `~/tmp/*` and one of the files is `~/tmp/list_update`, so effectively you order it to read and write to the same file with a redirection and system is refusing to do that.

You also didn't specify `run_once`, so the `merge files from different hosts in once` task will run as there are hosts defined for the play.

*If you are sure `~/tmp/list_update` didn't exist beforehand, adding `run_once: true` to that task would resolve the problem, but it's far from the best way.*

---

Long story short, you can achieve what you want in one task, for example

- with a Jinja2 template:

  ```
  - copy:
      content: "{% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}{{ hostvars[host].update_deb_packs.stdout }}\n{% endfor %}"
      dest: ~/tmp/list_update
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
  ```

  You can add separators with `host`-value to indicate what data is coming from which host:

  ```
  content: "{% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}From host: {{ host }}\n{{ hostvars[host].update_deb_packs.stdout }}\n{% endfor %}"
  ```
- using operations on lists:

  ```
  content: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'update_deb_packs') | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"
  ```